# Bandwith quota in private network

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, linux-networking

We have a private company network with Linux and Windows networks.
All traffic to outside pass through a Debian firewall, managed by iptables.

We need to set a bandwith quota for every device: we need to avoid that Windows 10 updates fill all network bandwidth (according to `iftop`).

How can we set it?

Thank you.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth

Comment: I want a bandwith quota per user. Unix Stackexchange answers show how to limit all bandwith or to limit per program.